# Matplotlib hide sections of x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot, with an x axis range from -3 to 3, however the data generally clusters in either between -2 to -3 or 2 to 3 on the x-axis.

This means that there is a lot of wasted space on the graph between -2 and 2.

Is there a way in Matplotlib to customize the x axis, such that it goes:

-3, -2, 0, 2, 3

I.e the x-axis, between -2 to 0, and 0 to 2 is shortened or hidden to use up less space.